# When is WhatsApp Business API sending more that one element in "messages" array in inbound notifications?

Tags: whatsapp

As specified in WhatsApp Business API, one inbound notification message contain a `messages` property, that is an array of objects: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/webhooks/inbound#fields

I always find only one element in this array, and I'm not sure when to expect more messages or if it is even possible with current version of the API.

Does anynone know how a user can send two or more messages in the same inbound notification?

Comment: As comment, outbound notifications are handled in same webhook, and they will have no `messages` property (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/webhooks/outbound#fields)